# Ruby - How to write a new file with output from script

Tags: ruby

I have a simple script that does some search and replace. 
This is basically it:

```
File.open("us_cities.yml", "r+") do |file|
  while line = file.gets
  "do find a replace"
  end
  "Here I want to write to a new file"
end
```

As you can see I want to write a new file with the output. How can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Outputting to a new file can be done like this *(don't forget the second parameter)*:

```
output = File.open( "outputfile.yml","w" )
output << "This is going to the output file"
output.close
```

So in your example, you could do this :

```
File.open("us_cities.yml", "r+") do |file|
  while line = file.gets
    "do find a replace"
  end
  output = File.open( "outputfile.yml", "w" )
  output << "Here I am writing to a new file"
  output.close      
end
```

If you want to append to the file, make sure you put the opening of the output file outside of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

First you have to create a new file such as newfile.txt

Then change the script to

```
File.open("us_cities.yml", "r+") do |file|
  new_file = File.new("newfile.txt", "r+")
  while line = file.gets
  new_file.puts "do find a replace"
  end
end
```

This will make a new file with the output